# EXCEL: Count case sensitive criteria in one column if meets criteria in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, case-sensitive, multiple-conditions

My participants were asked 'who are you?' and asked to tick as many as applies to them. My list of possible answers are as follows:

```
Teacher
Teaching Assistant
SENCO
School Leader
Educational Psychology
Lunchtime Supervisor
School staff other
Parent
Researcher
Student
Person with neurodevelopmental condition
Other
```

This results in some participants producing responses with multiple answers like 'Teacher, Parent' or 'School staff other, Other'.

I want to count how many of each response there are for participants who answered a specific question. This means that I cannot simply write a formula that tests whether a cell = criteria, it must be that a cell contains the text, but be case specific, whilst also meeting criteria from another column.

I used the following formula to do this (R24 in this case referring to cell containing the word 'Teacher' and the latter part of the formula only including those who typed something in response to the question I am interested in).

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[[#All],[Who are you?]],"*"&R24&"*",Table1[[#All],[What was the most valuable thing that you learnt?]],"<>"&"")
```

This works fine for every response except 'Other'. As COUNTIFS is not case sensitive, the total produced for 'Other' includes that for those who also select 'School staff other'.

When trying to work this out, I can manage to produce a case sensitive total using the following formula (R35 being a cell containing the word 'Other' and the range being a set of dummy data like below):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(R35,R39:R49))))
```

---

```
Teacher, Parent
Teacher, Parent
Educational Psychology
SENCO, Other
Teacher
Other
School staff other
3
Other
SENCO, Other
School staff other, Other
```

However, I cannot find a way to add the additional criteria that this should only be counted for participants who answer the question i.e. do not have a blank cell in another column of data ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HyOP.png) for e.g. of dummy data including column of nonsense acting as answer to question, ignore % on left). You will see that my problem is that my formula for 'Other' counts the answer containing 'School staff other' as COUNTIFS is not case sensitive.

Please note that the example I give on the image is all on one worksheet whereas the formula needs to pull the data from a large dataset from other worksheets.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A12,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&x&",",", "&E1:E11&",")))))
```

If not supported, just scratch the iterative `MAP()`, but the main idea here is that you are using the fact that multiple answers are comma-space delimited. Use this to your advantage.

Comment: Does this work when drawing the data from separate worksheets? I have a totals sheet I am trying to enter this formula into to give total counts for each response. The data for the initial response and the answer to the question are on a much larger dataset on a different sheet. I've tried playing around with this formula you have given but I am not an expert at excel and as it does not reference a column of additional data specifically I don't think this would work across sheets.

Comment: Well, one could `VSTACK()` the response from different sources (assuming you mean that column E in above screenshot can grow due to this fact) to make this work across multiple worksheets. Come these newer dynamic array functions there are multiple ways of retrieving data that's spread out over multiple sheets. So, the answer would be **Yes** that's possible. @DSad

Comment: I can't figure out if the above formula is addressing my initial problem, which is that I need it to count each individual response whilst also maintaining the condition that there is text in another column of data. I can't see this formula accounting for the second condition. I also get the error SPILL when attempting to use above formula.

Comment: That could be done using boolean logic. Since there is no sample data actually showing another column, it's hard to answer this through a comment. It could look like something like: `=MAP(A1:A12,LAMBDA(x,SUM((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&x&",",", "&E1:E11&",")))*(F1:F11<>""))))`

Comment: Hi there, I have just attached image with dummy data so you can see the cell references etc. I also just used your most recent formula with my data and still get SPILL. I don't know how to remove MAP and still get the formula to work as suggested above.

Comment: 'SPILL#' error occurs because the spilled dynamic array has data sitting in it's destination cells. Just make sure you clear the other cells, and just use the suggested formula in the top cell @DSad

Comment: This seems to have worked! I don't understand the logic behind the formula as I am a complete novice but it seems to be doing what I want it to. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. If this has answered your question, feel free to mark the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of my post. @DSad

Comment: @JvdV this formula worked when testing with dummy data on one sheet using =MAP(R24:R35,LAMBDA(x,SUM((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&x&",",", "&R39:R49&",")))*(Q39:Q49<>"")))) but when I try to insert the original data across worksheets it does not and I get a NAME error =MAP(R24:R35,LAMBDA(x,SUM((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", "&x&",",", "&Table1[[#All],[Who are you?]]&",")))*(Table1[[#All],[What was the most valuable thing that you learnt?]]<>""))))

Comment: this still hasn't worked can you help?